# How to specify the execution time for generationg the pdf using dompdf

Tags: php

I'm trying to use dompdf to convert a large, dynamic PHP file into a PDF. It's a table-rich file, with 148,000 characters. When dompdf tries to convert it to a PDF file, I reach a maximum execution time. I decided to change the max_execution_time to 100 seconds, and now it just goes to a blank page and doesn't output anything.

Is there a way fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you configured PHP to display or log errors?

Comment: yes. I have specified the ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Answer (score 0):

I was doing such task using PDFlib, size of file was less but time of generation pdf file was about 1 sec. You can read more about pdflib here: `http://www.pdflib.com/developer/technical-documentation/manuals/`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you configure your development box to display **all** possible errors. You have several ways to do so:

1. Edit your "php.ini" file:

   ```
   error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
   display_errors = On
   ```
2. Put this on top of your script:

   ```
   <?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
   ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
   ```
3. If PHP runs as Apache module, you can also use an `.htaccess` file:

   ```
   # You cannot use PHP constants here
   php_value error_reporting -1
   php_flag display_errors on
   ```

Additionally, you should inspect the raw output as generated by PHP. Given that you probably have HTTP headers that tell the browser it's a binary file, you might need to save the page to disk and open it with a regular text editor (though good old View Page Source menu might do the trick depending on your browser).

As about your exact question, the way to specify the maximum execution time is always the same: call the [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/set_time_limit) function or change the [max_execution_time](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) directive.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

set_time_limit(0);

in your script or in php.ini set

max_execution_time = 0

not recommending to scripts open to the public but inside access controlled applications there are sometimes needs to use those options.